# Broadleaf: Paypal Integration Files not Found

Tags: broadleaf-commerce

Hi I Want To Integrate The Paypal with Broadleaf i Have followed the documentation of Broadleaf https://www.broadleafcommerce.com/docs/paypal/current/
 But  i am not able to find a file named **payPalPaymentMethodForm.html** and **cartOperations.html** in My Broadleaf-site and I am Using The Community Version of broadleaf

Can any One Help me to Solve The Issue

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

/site/src/main/resources/webTemplates/checkout/payment/payPalPaymentMethodForm.html

/site/src/main/resources/webTemplates/cart/partials/cartOperations.html